# Count result date when they are equals

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, count, sql-convert

I only need Date where they are not repeated like:

```
    Date           Quantity
    2017-06-20     9
    2017-08-18     88
    2017-06-21     30
```

So I tried:

```
select CONVERT(date, UpdatedDate) as 'Date', COUNT(*) as 'Flights Quanttity'
from FlightSchedules
group by UpdatedDate
```

but I get something like:

```
Date           Quantity
2017-08-08     1
2017-06-20     1
2017-08-18     88
2017-06-20     16
2017-06-20     8
```

Because the date have hours it show the dates repeated, like the convert is just an output transformation, its counting the hours of that day separated, but I need to count flights for day with any hour on Quantity.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
group by CONVERT(date, UpdatedDate)
```

Instead of :

```
group by UpdatedDate
```